# Excluding dependency transitively for assembly only?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm using the sbt-assembly plugin for packaging a fat jar. I have a dependency that I need when running the app locally (with `sbt run`), however, I need to exclude it (including its transitive dependencies, which it has many) during `assembly`. I can't find a way to do this. Is this possible?

Comment: In the other question, there's also a one-liner solution by @douglaz, which is better than my "unprovided", so I'm voting to close this one so all good ideas go there.